# How to execute other function after @Url.Action with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my mvc application i use the @url.action to get new data and show it in the page. The problem that i have right now is that i want to excute more javascript after the @url.action

```
function find(elm)
    {
        var keyWord = $('input', $(elm).parent()).val();
        $('#searchResults').load('@Url.Action("Search", "Search")', { 
        searchText: keyWord });
        // I want to load here a other function aswell
    }
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: load supports the ability to pass a callback function.  why can't you use that?

Comment: Please read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute your other functions inside the complelte call back of jQuery `load` method

```
var keyWord ="dummy";
var url='@Url.Action("Search", "Search")';

$('#searchResults').load(url, {searchText: keyWord },function(){
    alert("Load complete.Do somethign else now");
});
```

The callback function will be executed when the xhr request completes.

You can also use `$.post` where you can do your custom stuff inside the `done` event. You can also wire up a `fail` event as well to catch errors.

```
var keyWord ="dummy";
var url='@Url.Action("Search", "Search")';
$.post(url, {searchText: keyWord }).done(function(r) {
     $('#searchResults').html(r);
     alert("ajax call done.Do somethign else now");
}).fail(function(x, a, e) {
    console.log(x);
    console.log(a);
    alert(e);
});
```